# How to change the kibana GUI login password without Xpack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Need to change the Kibana GUI password. I have to change the password in the customer system so I can't install Xpack. Please provide the solution.

Comment: Hi, and welcome on SO. I'll suggest to read [ask], [mcve] and [tour]. If you have some problems/error we are glade to help you., but here nobody will code for you.

Comment: You can't, authentication on Kibana needs a license, from version 6.8 and 7.1 the basic authentication, which stores the user/password in elasticsearch is free with de basic license, any other integration with AD ou Single Sign-On need a Gold or Platinum subscription.

Answer (score 0):

1. What ES version you are using?
2. What do you mean by Kibana GUI password? Is it Kibana user? or Superuser? or Some other user?

Since you are using 5.2 as mentioned in your comments, here's the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.2/security-getting-started.html#security-getting-started) for ES 5.2.

The command in your case would be:

```
curl -XPUT -u kibana:kibanauser 'http://localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/kibana/_password' -d '{ "password": "kibana2019"}'
```

In SO, as a good practise, you need to specify what you tried and what didn't work

Comment: ES version : 5.2.1

Comment: Kibana :  Username is "kibana" and password is "kibanauser" but we need to change password as "kibana2019".

Comment: How to apply the post request in elasticsearch/kibana?

Comment: bash-4.2$ curl -XPUT -u kibana:kibanauser 'http://localhost:9201/_xpack/security/user/kibana/_password' -d '{ "password": "kibana2019"}
>
>
>
>

Comment: After executing that command, it is showing > like this. I am executing that command in elastic search, is it correct?

Comment: Check that you are not missing the closing `'` at the end

Comment: No handler found for uri [/_xpack/security/user/kibana/_password] and method [PUT]bash-4.2$

Comment: You've to install x-pack. Go to `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin` or whichever directory you've installed x-pack in and then run `./elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack`. This requires that the machine is connected to internet. Else download x-pack-5.2.1.zip and install it using `./elasticsearch-plugin install file:///<location_for_xpack-5.2.1.zip>

Comment: @LaptopGuru - if the answer helped you, can you please consider accepting it. Thanks.